# Reading file with fscanf in C

Tags: c

I have c code that reads the file in a while loop, fscanf all the information into url, num and rank variables, and then prints it out. However, the output is incorrect.

Main questions:

- Why floats are just zeros and how can to fix this?
- How to remove comma after url? Url can be any length (char url[10] is an example). Would it be better to split the line first on every comma and then use fscanf to add information into variable?

I have a file containing following information:

```
url31, 3, 0.2623546
url21, 1, 0.1843112
url34, 6, 0.1576851
url22, 4, 0.1520093
url32, 6, 0.0925755
url23, 4, 0.0776758
url11, 3, 0.0733884
```

This is what I get:

```
Link: url21,; Number: 1; Rank: 0.000000
Link: url34,; Number: 6; Rank: 0.000000
Link: url22,; Number: 4; Rank: 0.000000
Link: url32,; Number: 6; Rank: 0.000000
Link: url23,; Number: 4; Rank: 0.000000
Link: url11,; Number: 3; Rank: 0.000000
Link: url11,; Number: 3; Rank: 0.000000
```

Expected output:

```
Link: url31; Number: 3; Rank: 0.2623546
Link: url21; Number: 1; Rank: 0.1843112
Link: url34; Number: 6; Rank: 0.1576851
Link: url22; Number: 4; Rank: 0.1520093
Link: url32; Number: 6; Rank: 0.0925755
Link: url23; Number: 4; Rank: 0.0776758
Link: url11; Number: 3; Rank: 0.0733884
```

The code I have:

```
#define MAXSTR 1000

int main () {

    FILE *file;

    char url[10];
    int num;
    float rank;

    if ((file = fopen("pages.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while(fgets(lines, MAXSTR, file) != NULL) {

        fscanf(file, "%s %d %f", &url[0], &num, &rank);
        printf("Link: %s; Number: %d; Rank: %f\n", url, num, rank); 

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `fscanf` format string doesn't automatically recognize a comma as a field delimeter. Specifically, for example, `%s ` will scan for a string followed by space, which will read in `url31,` as the first string (remember, comma is just another non-blank character to `fscanf`). The number looks like it's being read correctly but the wrong order. Are you sure what you show is the order of the lines in the file you read? The `%d` ends scanning at the comma, then the scan tries to read the comma as a float, which gives you 0's for that.

Comment: Those are semicolons, not commas, but that's the problem - maybe write it as an answer?

Comment: @lurker Yes, I understand why it reads comma into %s, is there a way I could fix this? I copied file as it is, so everything should be in correct order - url (str), number (int), rank (float).

Comment: @CarlNorum semicolons are in the formatted printf, it was my choice to add them, so it can be more visible that it reads comma into the string.

Comment: @CarlNorum it's commas in the original, read text file.

Comment: Oh wow, I am bad at reading.

Comment: 'char url[10];'  why 10?   What is wrong with, say, [128] ?  Shtap with the bean-counting:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `fgets` if you are already using `fscanf` (just keep scanning until you find an `EOF`) as well inside your while loop. Also, you need to properly define the `,` as a delimiter otherwise the first `%s` will read commas into the string as well. This `while` loop works:

```
while(fscanf(file, "%10[^,], %d, %f\n", url, &num, &rank) != EOF) {
    printf("Link: %s; Number: %d; Rank: %f\n", url, num, rank); 
}
```

I defined the delimiter as a comma, so the first string should read the characters until a comma is encountered via `%10[^,]` (read upto 10 characters as mentioned in the format-specifier), followed by a comma, integer, comma, float and then a newline (`\n`).

Output:

```
Link: url31; Number: 3; Rank: 0.262355
Link: url21; Number: 1; Rank: 0.184311
Link: url34; Number: 6; Rank: 0.157685
Link: url22; Number: 4; Rank: 0.152009
Link: url32; Number: 6; Rank: 0.092575
Link: url23; Number: 4; Rank: 0.077676
Link: url11; Number: 3; Rank: 0.073388
```

Comment: Your code will exhibit buffer overrun behavior if/when the link field exceeds the length of url.

Comment: You mean to say OP's code, I will suggest to use a dynamically-allocated `char *` instead. The OP just mentioned the size as an example as they said in the question, so I assumed they are wary of the size limits.

Comment: No, I mean the url buffer has a limited length and you did not inform `fscanf` of that fact.

Comment: I got what you mean, added. Thanks.

Comment: `== 3` makes more sense here than `!= EOF`.  `%10[^,]` better as `%9[^,]`.  10 is the wrong width.  Suggest `" %9[^,] ,%d ,%f`"`.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes because the lines in your code gave me errors (probably from compiler or IDE, not sure). It works this way because the comma is not considered a space character.

`% 5 [^,]` means read until you encounter a maximum of five characters or commas.

- For example, because `url31` has 5 characters, I gave this so you can give different numbers for different operations.

  #include <stdio.h>

  int main () {

  ```
    FILE *fp;

    char url[10];

    int num;

    float rank;

    fp = fopen("pages.txt" , "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return(-1);
    }
        while(fscanf(fp, "%5[^,], %d, %f\n", url, &num, &rank) != EOF) {
        printf("Link: %s; Number: %d; Rank: %f\n", url, num, rank);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return(0);
  ```

  }